# How to represent the even signed permutations by Young tableaux?

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, young-tableaux

The well-known RSK correspondence established the connection between table pair (P,Q) and the permutations in symmetry group Sn(Coxeter group of type A). Also, there is a similar correspondence for the hyperoctahedral group Bn (Coxeter group of type B)(see e.g. Stanley
Some aspects of groups acting on finite posets.
J. Combin. Theory Ser. A 32 (1982) 132–161.). My question is: Is there a similar correspondence for Coxeter group of type D, i.e., How to represent the even signed permutations by Young tableaux?

Comment: [Cedric Lecouvey, *Schensted-type correspondences and plactic monoids for types $B_{n}$ and $D_{n}$*, arXiv:math/0211444v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211444v1) claims a bumping algorithm in type D. (h/t Travis Scrimshaw)

Comment: @Sam a dozen retags of old questions in two hours, driving newer questions off the front page – please don't do that. Do three or four a day, please.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: sorry; got it.